# How to add Youtube video in the background of HTML section

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have a HTML section in which i want to add a youtube video in the background but i am not able to do it.Here is the HTML to add youtube video in the background..

```
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_OBlgSz8sSM"></iframe>
    </div>
```

and here is the Fiddle link..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zg19rwqg/)

Please help me to add this video in the background of section..

Comment: so you want the the text to be over the video right ?

Comment: @Youness Yes ..its right...

Comment: answerd , i tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS :

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    top:0px;

}
```

here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Youness/zg19rwqg/2/)**